# How to get Character Value from an Integer database field

Tags: html, angularjs, django

I have an integer field in db, which is option field. I'm saving the options in terms of id in to the db, but I also have to display the value in that field pertaining to certain operations. Can anyone here please tell me how to get a text value from an int field and display it? Below is my code:

Html:

```
<th col width="55%"><label><strong>Risk Estimation</strong></label>

               <select ng-model="arform.risk_estimate"
                       ng-options="item for item in risk_estimate">
                  <option style="display:none" value=" risk_estimate.text"></option>
               </select>
            </th>
```

Controller:

```
{{ngapp}}.controller(
        "SiVerifyAddReviewController",
        function($scope, $http, $modalInstance, r_header){

$scope.risk_estimate = ['High','Medium', 'Low'];};
```

Will be able to provide if further part of code is required for understanding. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display

```
{{ object.get_field_display }}
```

Comment: It works. Thanks! Any Idea how to do for a checkbox field? get_field_display is for only for choices or can be used for checkbox too?

Comment: @SURYAVISWANATHAN no it doesn't. It works only for choice made fields. But. You can create a cached_property on your model say `get_some_field_display` and inside that property return hardcoded string or do some calculations. Then in templates just do the usual {{ object.get_some_field_display }}

Comment: By cached_property, do you mean using patch_cache_control? If possible, Could you give me an example where I can use cached_property in model? I'm new here. Thanks.

Comment: No, this. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/utils/#django.utils.functional.cached_property Just store the name of the field in a property of a model and you will have it templates too.

Comment: Thanks! It worked. I'm expecting an answer for one more Question I posted recently. If possible, Could you take a look at it and give your inputs?

Comment: Below is the link for the Q http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40121484/pass-value-from-view-to-controller-and-display-in-template

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you need to get selected option text when ever it will change or submitted right?, then you need to represent all options like this in a way so you will get whole object of option which is selected, then you can extract the value of even text from it.
Follow this:

```
<select  ng-model="selectOption" ng-change="changedValue(selectOption)" 
 data-ng-options="option as allOptions.name for option in allOptions">
<option value="">Select Account</option>
```

// Controller will be like this :

```
function ctrl($scope){
    $scope.itemList=[];
    $scope.allOptions=[{id:1,name:"a"},{id:2,name:"b"},{id:3,name:"c"}]

    $scope.changedValue=function(item){
    $scope.itemList.push(item.name);
    }    

}
```

Comment: Yes. You're right. I need to display the submitted value. What does ng-change do in your code? Could you send me the controller function(of ng-change) also?

Comment: @SURYAVISWANATHAN : Of course, please see updated code.

Comment: @SURYAVISWANATHAN : Was it worked for you?, let me know, otherwise will provide you another alternative solution in case of if you can't change your code. (Please up vote it as well :))

Comment: Hey. The other answer here, is much more easier and it worked for me. I din't try yours, as I don't want to disturb my html. Thanks anyways!

Comment: No problem , Welcome :)