# Initialize two values with an if in template-django

Tags: angularjs, django

I have a condition where I need to display values depending on an if condition. Below is my template code.

Template:

```
<td>
  <label>Review Title/Purpose*</label>
</td></br>
<div ng-if="title1 == true">
<td>
  <input type="text" class="col-md-10" maxlength="256" ng-show="title1" ng-model="arform.revtitle"><required/>
</td></div>

<div ng-if="title1 != true">
<td><input type="text" class="col-md-10" maxlength="256" ng-show="!title1" ng-init="'{{reviewtit}}'" ng-model="arform.revtitle"><required/>
</td></div>
```

The value in `ng-init="'{{reviewtit}}'"` is the value I get from Views. Where as  the value in `ng-show="title1"` is the value I get from controller.

I just wanted to know is it right to use ng-show in the different ways I mentioned?

Comment: There's no IF condition here in the code.

Comment: Edited with if condition. Only the true condition works.

Comment: Is it Django or angular question, I don't get it.

Comment: angular part is v less. The above html is executed on two different modals.  The GUI is the same for both the modals. Just that, the value in the input field is differed. Currently, I'm able to see only with the condition that title1==true. (i.e In the first modal). The other modal should have the value(title1!=true). It's not working. Would you see any error in the usage of ng-if? Any other new approaches is also welcome.