# Modal opens only after clicking twice when submitted for the first time from a button

Tags: html, django, bootstrap-modal

I have a modal popup to be opened from a button click. Unfortunately, I'm able to see the popup only after clicking twice when it is submitted for the first time in the browser. But once the popup is opened and closed, I'm able to open the modal with a single click on the next attempts. The same happens if I refresh my browser. This looks strange. Any body can explain, why? I have the following code,

Button html:

```
<div><button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" ng-disabled="{{update_problem_description_disabled}}" ng-click="siverifyAddReviewModal()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i> Edit Review </button>
    </div>
```

Modal html:

```
<div class="modal-header container-fluid">

   {% include "siverify_modal_header.html" %}
</div>
<form class="well form-horizontal" name="addReviewForm">
   {% csrf_token %}
   <div id="form-modal-body" class="modal-body">
      {% verbatim %}
      <table class="table" style="width:90%">
          <tr>
              <th><label>Review Title/Purpose*</label></th></br>
                {% endverbatim %}

              <td><input type="text" class="col-md-10" maxlength="256" ng-model="arform.revtitle" value="arform.revtitle"  required/></td>

              <!--<td><input type="text" class="col-md-10" maxlength="256" ng-init="'{{reviewtit}}'" ng-model="arform.revtitle"  > {{reviewtit}} </td>-->

          </tr>
<div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"
              ng-disabled="addReviewForm.$invalid || rev_submit_disabled"
              ng-click="addReview(arform)">Save</button>
      <button type="button" ng-click="cancel()"
              class="btn btn-small btn-warning">Cancel</button>
   </div>
 </form>
```

Modal function

```
$scope.siverifyAddReviewModal = function(wpts,mask,lyr,tech) {
        // function to open modal and link to Modal Controller

        $scope.addRevModal = function(wptSet) {
            context = $scope.get_problem_stmt_context(dtWorklist, context_getter);
            //console.log("dtw", dtWorklist);
            var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                backdrop: 'static',
                templateUrl: '{% url 'siverify_add_review' %}',
                controller: 'SiVerifyAddReviewController',
                resolve:{
                        r_header: function(){ return wptSet; },
                        context: function(){ return context; }
                }
            });
           modalInstance.result.then(function () {
                datatable_worklist.refresh();
                $log.info('Modal success');

                //console.log(msg);
                }, function () {
                    $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
            });
        };
        //End:function to open modal and link to Modal Controller
```

Comment: Where's the code which opens the modal?

Comment: Added the modal function

Comment: Yep cheers. And the code of the element that opens the modal please.

Comment: Code of the element that opens the modal - I don't understand what you're asking! I have given the modal function in button html.(ng-click).

Comment: Ah, yep. Try changing it to `ng-change`. Is it still opening from the second time?

Comment: Yes. Tried using ng-change in place of ng-click. Still the same. Able to open it only from the second time.

Comment: Hm, don't know really. Also I don't really see `addReview ` function here.

Comment: It's most likely that you execute this code before Angular itself.

Comment: I see. Will check that up. Thanks for your time!

Comment: @Andrey. ideas?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40523493/how-to-check-for-a-value-if-it-exists-in-a-different-database-table