# How to check for a value if it exists in a different database table

Tags: html, angularjs, django

I have a scenario where I should display an image when a value of one field of a table is present in another table. I'm not sure how this condition can be done. Can anybody help? In html or even in angularjs. For better understanding, my code in html and what I'm trying to do,

**html:**

```
{% if {{vio.pdb_pid}}   }
    {% if is_secure_device == 'true'%}
        {% verbatim %}
            <img class="img-rounded" ng-src="{{vio.pdb_pattern_img}}">
        {% endverbatim %}
```

Model which has {{vio.pdb_pid}} value:

```
class OrcPattern(models.Model):
   pdb_id = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Model of the other table:

```
class SiverifyVerificationSite(models.Model):
 pattern_id = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
```

My first line in the code.i.e. the if statement is incomplete. the value `{{vio.pdb_pid}}` should be checked on a table called `sivorcdds(the field name in this table is pdb)`. Precisely, if `{{vio.pdb_pid}}` exists in pattern_id.SiverifyVerificationSite(fieldname.tablename)` I should display an image as like in my code. I don't know how to do this. I'm new to coding. Any help would be appreciated.

Note: The two models are of different applications.

Comment: This is far too vague, I'm afraid. You'll need to at least show your models to see how the "other table" is related. But it sounds like this is the sort of thing that would be done in your Django view.

Comment: Added the models of both tables. If it could be done view, any idea how? may be want to take a look at views file too? I thought it can be done in html itself. or probably angular.

Comment: Yes, you should show the view. I'm afraid I still don't understand what "pattern_id.SiverifyVerificationSite(fieldname.tablename)" is or what it would mean for vio.db_pid to "exist" there.

Comment: vio.pdb_pid is a value in  OrcPattern model. I just wanted to check if this value is in pattern_id field of siverifyverificationsite model.

Comment: Should one of those fields be a foreign key, perhaps?

Comment: None of the field is a foreign key. Since the models are of different applications.

Comment: I have no idea what that "since" means; foreign keys work fine across applications.